# I can't use sscanf in linux, thouh i have include the header file

Tags: c++, gdb

This is my code, and I have included the header file "stdio.h"

```
string expression(content, s, content.length());
//getline(contentFlow, expression, '\n');
double a = 0.0, b = 0.0;
bool isValueOperation = false;
if (sscanf(expression.c_str(), "%lf,%lf)", &a, &b) != 2)
{
    isValueOperation = true;
    sscanf(expression.c_str(), "%lf)", &a);
}
displayHead("");
```

and when I compile the file, the compiler gives no error message. However, when I use gdb,I find that I have another error message, that is

[image: the error message in gdb]
it's just about it can find such file or directory and I'm very confused since I can successfully compile it.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this the error? `[![the error message in gdb][1]][1]`
Is it a C or C++ code?

Comment: What makes you think that `sscanf` is causing this error?

Comment: Writing a multi-language source file is **hard**. I suggest you keep to only one of C or C++.

Comment: You're hitting a breakpoint. That isn't an error…

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` is the right format.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text terminals.

Comment: Please copy/paste your terminal output instead of posting a photo of it.

Comment: but the gdb says no such file and if i continuously enter s, i will get the message "genops.c no such file or directory" and then there will be endless "in genops c" if i still enter s

Comment: This is an information message, not an error. It informs you that you don't have a file named `sscanf.c` which contains the source code of `sscanf`. This is not surprising because you didn't write this function. It's a part of the standard library. The standard library is not normally distributed in the source code form (but you can get the sources and compile it yourself if you really want to).

Comment: thanks for all your kind deeds, from another questions I actually can find the answers, thanks! But if I thought the income of sscanf is right and the  outcome of sscanf is contrary to my expectations, how can I use some tools to fix the problem. Is it just meaning my code logic have problems?